# Text Search in Flask and Python Using flask-whooshalchemy

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask, full-text-search

I have undergone similar posting in text search using Flask-WhooshAlchemy. But none of the search provide concrete results and none of these address blueprints.

My task is to search text using flask and python from database. My database is MySQL and I am using SQLAlchemy for it.

My sturcture of program looks like:

```
BlogPost
    Admin
    __init__.py
    forms.py
    views.py
    User
     __ init__.py
    forms.py
    views.py
__init__.py
models.py
```

**init**.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask_whooshalchemy as whooshalchemy
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =      'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'app_v29.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['WHOOSE_BASE'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'app_v29.db')
```

models.py

```
import flask_whooshalchemy as whooshalchemy
from BlogPost import app

class Task_Add(db.Model):
    __searchable__ =['task_add']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    task_add = db.Column(db.String(64))
    def __init__(self,task_add):
        self.task_add = task_add

   def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.task_add}"  
 whooshalchemy.whoosh_index(app, Task_Add)  

class Invoice_Add(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
invoice_add = db.Column(db.String(64))
def __init__(self,invoice_add):
    self.invoice_add = invoice_add

def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.invoice_add}"
```

views.py

```
@adminDash.route('/view_task')
def view_task():
    task_all=Task_Add.query.all()
    return render_template('admin/view_task.html',task_all=task_all)

@adminDash.route('/search_task')
def search_task():
    q=request.args.get('query')
    task_all=Task_Add.query.whoosh_search(q).all()
    return render_template('admin/view_task.html',task_all=task_all)
```

view_task.html

```
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
              <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-insert">
                <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{url_for('adminDash.search_task')}}">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" id="query">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              </div>
            <!-- .card -->
            <section id="base-style" class="card">
              <!-- .card-body -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <!-- .form -->
                <div class="lits-group list-group-flush">
                  <!-- .lits-group-item -->
                  <!-- .table-responsive -->
                               <div class="table-responsive">
                                 <!-- .table -->
                                 <table class="table table-sm mb-0">
                                   <!-- thead -->
                                   <thead class="thead-">
                                     <tr>
                                       <th><font color="#0f1f94"> Task</font></th>
                                       <th><font color="#0f1f94"> Delete</font></th>
                                     </tr>
                                   </thead>
                                   <!-- /thead -->
                                   <!-- tbody -->
                                   <tbody>
                                     <!-- tr -->
                                     <tr>
                                       {% for task_in in task_all %}
                                       <td> {{task_in.task_add}} </td>
                                       <td>
                                         <form action="{{url_for('adminDash.delete_task',task_post_id=task_in.id)}}" method="POST">
                                           <button type="submit" class="far fa-trash-alt"></button>
                                         </form>
                                       </td>
                                     </tr>
                                      {% endfor %}
                                 </tbody>
                               </table>
                             </div>

          <!-- .lits-group-item -->
                </div>


              </div>
    </div>
```

When I search a query in search button, it sends text to /search_task but

```
task_all=Task_Add.query.whoosh_search(q).all()
```

gives [] in the results though if query using

```
task_all=Task_Add.query.all()
```

it will gives query.

Thank you to let me know where I make mistake. And how to use Flask-WhooshAlchemy in blueprints?

Thanks